# Regex For Parsing Object Literal

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to parse out a JavaScript object literal from a script block on a page.  Here's the example I have of the data:

```
//End Update for CASE00370003 2011/08/22
stores[0] = {
'fullName' : 'Bobs Commons',
'street1' : '23 Chestnut Commons Dr'
};
//Some more comments
stores[1] = {
'fullName' : 'Gove Wood',
'street1' : '65 Lake Rd'
};
```

So far I've come up with:

```
/^(stores\[)(\d){1,2}(])(.|\n)*};$/m
```

However, the string ends with "};" will grab the last occurrence of the }; on stores[1], so each won't be broken individually.  Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use `/^stores\[(\d+)](.*?);/` Match everything up until the semicolon?

Comment: You can't really parse an object literal, in general, with a regex. Luckily, there's no need to do that, because you can just let JavaScript parse it.

Comment: I am scraping information from an HTTP response. So there is no JavaScript.

Comment: Which language are you using to scrape the information? See if there’s a JavaScript parser for it. :)

Comment: C#. I am reading a raw html response with tags... there's a <script> section that would be read in by javascript to create the global array. I just need to parse the data out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that what you need is 'non-greedy' matches (`*?` instead of `*`) - it captures the shortest match rather than the longest.
So the regex will look like:

```
/^(stores\[)(\d){1,2}(])(.|\n)*?};$/m
```

After suggesting that I still have to note that you in general should **not** do that with regular expressions at all :). Your approach will break if the object string properties contain '}' (e.g., 'fullName' : 'Bobs Comm}ons').

Comment: As long as the data ends with }; I am good to go!  This works! Thank you!

Comment: The groups here seem a little arbitrary. Are any of them actually needed? Seems to me like it should be `/(?:^|\n)stores\[(\d+)\].*?};/`.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the @amakhrov answer above:

you may perform consecutive searches of closing curly brace unless `JSON.parse(literal_string);` executes without exceptions

UPD: missed the important fact, that for that it needs to be a valid JSON

Answer (score -2):

PREPARE TO HAVE YOUR MIND BLOWN.

J.S.O.N. (the thing several answers have mentioned)
--->

**J** ava-**S** cript **O** bject **N** otation.

Cool, right? Since JS' declaration syntax is so useful, it became a neutral data format. That's the format your web request is returning, and JavaScript even has special libraries for parsing it. I think you may have just been unclear on that part.

Comment: "That's the format your web request is returning" --- it's not. It looks like, but it's not JSON

Comment: Prepare to have your mind blown. Its not JSON... Its an object literal stored in an array. Regardless, horrible answer and attitude.